# return an observable from a finalize method on observable

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs

Concrete case is this: 
AngularFirebase documentation says that in order to get the download URL from an uploaded file, you need to do this:

```
const task = this.storage.upload(filePath, file);

// observe percentage changes
// get notified when the download URL is available
task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL() )
 )
.subscribe();
}
```

Now, I have an upload method and I want to return from it, an observable of string. My method signature looks like :

```
upload(file :File) :Observable<string> {

......

}
```

I tried doing this :

```
return <Observable<string>>task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize(() => {
            const url = fileRef.getDownloadURL();
            console.log('download url is ',url);
            return url;
        })
    );
```

But this doesn't work because, there are other elements of type snapshot changes in the original observable.

Now my question is, how I can use the code in the example to effectively return the type I want

Comment: Just remove the `subscribe`, and return what you've got

Comment: That doesn't work. I updated the question

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Add (after the `finalize`) `map(() => fileRef.getDownloadURL())`. Not sure where you're getting `fileRef` from, but the `map` function will transform the value being emitted by the Observable

Comment: That fires too many times. This works https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-nqcr4w but ugly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the documentation, `finalize`...

> Returns an Observable that mirrors the source Observable, but will call a specified function when the source terminates on complete or error.

That means, you cannot alter the Observable type with the passed function.

Instead, you can combine the `last` operator and the `map` operator to get a notification for the last value, mapped to the desired property. It would look like this:

```
return <Observable<string>>task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        last(),
        map(() => {
            const url = fileRef.getDownloadURL();
            console.log('download url is ',url);
            return url;
        })
    );
```

Comment: That is very nice, and almost worked, except for the fact that `fileRef.getDownloadURL()` returns an observable itself! so it ends up being and ovservable<observable<string>>

Comment: Alright, that should be no problem; just replace `map` with `mergeMap` ;-)

Comment: good idea, but be careful it throws an error if your source observable hasn't emitted a value yet!

Comment: very cool thanks. bit skeptical with the `last` though. how does rxjs know that `last` is infact `last`? is it based on the `complete` method of the observer?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and here is my solution

```
return <Observable<string>>task
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(
        last(),
        flatMap(
          () => {
            return fileRef.getDownloadURL().pipe(
              map((url) => {
                return url;
              })
            );
          }
        )
      );
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please check [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.